# Get AWS Reservation Utilization by custom tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-elemental, aws-media-live

I am currently assigning AWS media-live channels to a specific group by a custom tag and want to get the (CostExplorer) GetReservationUtilization for a group's channels by filtering by tag. The [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_GetReservationUtilization.html) for GetReservationUtilization lists the Filtering options as:

```
"Filter": {
    .
    .
    "Tags": { 
        "Key": "string",
        "MatchOptions": [ "string" ],
        "Values": [ "string" ]
    }
    .
    .
}
```

I interpret it as it should be possible to sort by a custom set tag via:

```
"Key": "Group",
"Value": [customId]
```

But I get an error that says `"An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetReservationUtilization operation: Tags expression is not allowed, allowed expression(s): And, Not, Dimensions"`

Feels like I have tried everything possible but I cant seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming here in the future, sorting reservation-utilization by the tag dimension is currently not supported. The following dimensions are supported:

- AZ
- CACHE_ENGINE
- DEPLOYMENT_OPTION
- INSTANCE_TYPE
- LINKED_ACCOUNT
- OPERATING_SYSTEM
- PLATFORM
- REGION
- SERVICE
- SCOPE
- TENANCY

As specified in the [AWS API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_GetReservationUtilization.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the examples [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html#CostExplorer.Client.get_reservation_utilization) documentation?

Seems you may need to wrap the tag element inside of the And, Not or supply dimensions